# What's the best practice?

Tags: java

What is the best way to do this check in java?

```
        BigDecimal valorAtualizado = dotacaoPersist.buscarValorAtualizadoGastoComPessoal(codAdm, anoRef, codFunc);
        if(valorAtualizado != null){
            return valorAtualizado;
        }
            return BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

OR

```
        BigDecimal valorAtualizado = dotacaoPersist.buscarValorAtualizadoGastoComPessoal(codAdm, anoRef, codFunc);
        if(valorAtualizado != null){
            return valorAtualizado;
        }else{
            return BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }
```

Comment: `return whatever.do();` ?

Comment: They both look the same @ the assembly level if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: Both the solutions are nearby the same. Also you can minimize the code

Comment: In terms of understanding, I would prefer the second one. It is easier to understand the logic. But is this question about, which is the best practice or which has the best performance?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/120356

Answer (score 6):

Both versions are equivalent to this one line

```
return whatever.do();
```

Comment: Evgeniy Dorofeev you are right both versions are equivalent so instead of both use like your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this -

```
return (null!=a ? a : null);
```

But it is not a good idea returning a null from the calling method. Instead you can return some dummy value. For example you are trying to get a `studentList` from a `getStudents()` method. Then instead of returning a `null` you can return a empty list of student -

```
public List<Student> getStudents(){

 List<Student> studentList =  someMethodReturnsStudentList();

 return (null!=studentList ? studentList : Collections.EMPTY_LIST);

}
```

The benefit of using this technique is client methods using `getStudent()` don't need to think about the null checking further.

Hope it will help.